# OpenCV: How to stitch images into a long image vertically instead of panoramas/horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-stitching

I try to create an app which could stitch iPhone screenshots vertically as instance below shows. It would ignore the overlap part of images array and stitch the unique parts in correct order.

I have looked some tutorials in the internet and I think `openCV` framework could do this job, since it has the support to stitch images panoramas/horizontally. So I integrate this pod in my project and make it work on panoramas images stitching.

But I get troubles for stitching images vertically. From `CVWrapper.mm` I could see this method `processWithArray` would rotate and create the new stitched image from the images array. And currently, all my images in the array are with orientation `up`.

My question: is that possible to change this orientation so let `openCV` to stitch the images from top and down instead of left and right? I'm kind of lost in those orientation thins, have no clue where should I start this by now. Any hint/advice would be appreciated.

##### CVWrapper.mm

```
+ (UIImage*) processWithArray:(NSArray*)imageArray
{
    if ([imageArray count]==0){
        NSLog (@"imageArray is empty");
        return 0;
        }
    std::vector<cv::Mat> matImages;

    for (id image in imageArray) {
        NSLog(@"image orientation: %ld", (long)[image imageOrientation]);
        
        if ([image isKindOfClass: [UIImage class]]) {
            /*
             All images taken with the iPhone/iPa cameras are LANDSCAPE LEFT orientation. The  UIImage imageOrientation flag is an instruction to the OS to transform the image during display only. When we feed images into openCV, they need to be the actual orientation that we expect them to be for stitching. So we rotate the actual pixel matrix here if required.
             */
            UIImage* rotatedImage = [image rotateToImageOrientation];
            cv::Mat matImage = [rotatedImage CVMat3];
            NSLog (@"matImage: %@",image);
            matImages.push_back(matImage);
        }
    }
    NSLog (@"stitching...");
    cv::Mat stitchedMat = stitch (matImages);
    UIImage* result =  [UIImage imageWithCVMat:stitchedMat];
    return result;
}
```

##### UIImage+Rotate.m

```
- (UIImage *)rotateToImageOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;
    
    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;
            
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;
            
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
            
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }
    
    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;
            
        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }
    
    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

##### ViewController

```
    @objc func stitchButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        for imageView in [self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.imageView3] {
            imageView.isHidden = true
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            guard let images = self?.images else { return }
            let stitchedImage = CVWrapper.process(with: images)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let imageView = self?.longImageView else { return }
                UIView.transition(with: imageView,
                                  duration: 1.6,
                                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                  animations: {
                                    self?.longImageView.image = stitchedImage
                                    self?.longImageView.isHidden = false
                                  },
                                  completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

##### original 3 screenshots

[image]

##### stitched new long image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have solved this problem. In short, I rotate each image to 90 degree counterclockwize before processing them. So I never use method `rotateToImageOrientation` in `UIImage+Rotate.m`.

Now, this stitcher is working on most of in-app screenshots, but still has someones are not working. For details, go to [my blog](https://www.haibosfashion.com/posts/create%20long%20image%20stitcher%20app%20in%20swift/)